# Difference between frame.columnconfigure(...) and Grid.columnconfigure(frame,...)

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to Tkinter, specifically in Python 2.7 on Win7.

Is there a functional difference between the 2 following blocks of code? If so, what?

```
f = LabelFrame(pw_mid, text=" Frame Title ", width=400)
f.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(W, E))
Grid.columnconfigure(f, 0, weight=1)
```

and

```
f = LabelFrame(pw_mid, text=" Frame Title ", width=400)
f.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(W, E))
f.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

So: `Grid.columnconfigure(f,...)` vs. `f.columnconfigure(...)`

Thanks, Mark.

Comment: no difference. Use `f.columnconfigure(...)`.

Comment: @BryanOakley, this should be an answer, shouldn't it?

Comment: Thank you, Bryan.